# Проблема с установкой kweb на ubuntu 20.04: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package

Устанавливаю kweb

```
~$ wget http://steinerdatenbank.de/software/kweb-1.7.9.8.tar.gz
~$ tar -xzf kweb-1.7.9.8.tar.gz
~$ cd kweb-1.7.9.8
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
~/kweb-1.7.9.8$ ./debinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
Этот пакет невозможно установить
Dependency is not satisfiable: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

При этом libwebkitgtk-3.0.0 установлен

```
~$ dpkg -s libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
Package: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
Status: install ok installed
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что говорит `uname -a` ?

Comment: @eri Linux archie-pi 5.4.0-1021-raspi #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 5 09:59:23 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакета [libwebkitgtk-3.0-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=libwebkitgtk-3.0-0) нет для ubuntu 20.04, там перешли на libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37. Поэтому пакет для 18.04 не может найти зависимости. Попробуй вытащить пакет libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 и зависимости из 18.04, возможно заработает, но получается не всегда.

Собери лучше из исходников.